# Read Cookies From Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Is is possible to read cookies created in Firefox from a html page that was opended in Internet Explorer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[sorta](http://www.nuff-respec.com/technology/cross-browser-cookies-with-flash)... Cookies are stored in the browser, so you would need to hack around a bit to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Not without an ActiveX control and some very bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

not via javascript. The cookies are stored in a different location on disk.